# Why a maximal solution $u$ not identically zero admits at most a zero?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry for my bad english.

I have an other question about the differential equations and maximal solution.

Let $a : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, continuous, such as $a(t) > 0$, $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

We consider the differential equation $y''(t) = a(t)y(t)$.

Let $u$, a maximal solution of this equation, defined on $\mathbb{R}$, not identically zero. Then, we want to prove that $u$ have *at most* a zero on $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't see how to demonstrate it. Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you think of something? Convexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $u$ has two zeros $t_1,t_2$ ($t_1<t_2$) and $u$ does not zero in $(t_1,t_2)$. WLOG let $y>0$ in $(t_1,t_2)$, namely $y$ has a local maximum at some $t_0\in(t_1,t_2)$. Thus $y''(t_0)\le0$. Since $a(t)>0$, $y''=a(t)y(t)> 0$ in $(t_1,t_2)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you !

Comment: @MélanieDelaCheminée, you are welcome.

Comment: $y''(t_0)<0$ does not follow

Comment: @zhw., $y$ obtains a local maximum at $t_0$ and hence $y''(t_0)<0$.

Comment: the function $y=1$ attains a local max everywhere, but $y''=0.$

Comment: @zhw., remember $y(t_1)=y(t_2)=0$ and $y>0$ in $(t_1,t_2)$.

Comment: I addressed your reasoning, and showed that it fails. Now you give another reason. There's no hope: Look at $1-x^4$ on $[-1,1].$

Comment: @zhw., $1-x^4$ obtain the local max at $x=0$ and $(1-x^4)'|_{x=0}=0\le 0$ and hence nothing is wrong.

Comment: Nothing is wrong except your claim that $y''(t_0) < 0,$ which you stated not once, but twice, even after being corrected, and this is what I commented on.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $a<b, y(a)=y(b)=0,$ and $y\ne 0 $ on $(a,b).$ WLOG, $y >0$ on $(a,b).$ Your DE says then that $y''\ge 0$ on $[a,b].$ Does this seem likely?